# Dynamic Array to be created in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need to create a dynamic array whose elements may increase/decrease as per the value of an 'X' variable which the user specifies, I tried using CArray but VS 2010 does not support its header file, 'afxtempl.h', is there a work around? IF not, is there an function except CArray which is for c++ and not for compilers..
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use CArray since its meant for MFC, instead learn to love your STL. Use `std::vector`,

Check out, http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html for a quick reference

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector`. It is supported by C++ standard where as `CArray` is MFC specific. See [A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet creates a vector of 123 integers.

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int X = 123;
    vector<int> myContainerOfInts(X);

    myContainerOfInts[0] = 1;
}
```